# WordPress insert post error

Tags: php, wordpress

Calling this from a plugin:

```
$my_post = array(
 'post_title'    => 'Test',
 'post_content'  => 'Testing wp_insert_post()'
);

wp_insert_post($my_post);
```

results in a long error message:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function
>   is_user_logged_in() in C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Ampps\www\dev\wordpres....

Can anyone explain why and how to make this work please?

Comment: It's really helpful to know why people choose to downvote questions...

Comment: Can you please remove 'wp_insert_post()' from post_content and try again

Comment: Unfortunately no difference.

Comment: Maybe something to do with needing to ensure user is logged in?

Comment: add one more array element with 'post_type' key

i.e. 
$my_post = array(
 'post_title'    => 'Test',
 'post_content'  => 'Testing',
 'post_type' => 'post'
);

wp_insert_post($my_post);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying this code out side of WP structure then you need to place `require_once("path/to/wordpress/wp-load.php");` inclussion at top of the page.

But if not then you need to check your plugin. You can take a ride [here](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-is_user_logged_in/)

Comment: The solution from the above link is: "The problem is that is_user_logged_in is a pluggable function, and is therefore loaded after this plugin logic is called. The solution is to make sure that you don’t call this too early. This can be done by wrapping this logic in a function and calling it from ‘init’"